# Magento 1 : Cms Block collection

Tags: magento-1, cms, cms-block

`$collection = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();`

The above collection brings cms block table fields. How to add filter in these collections.

Comment: what kind of filter you want to add?

Comment: id add yes no dropdown in cms block after status now i want filter collection on list page  show thos cms blocks if  dropwon yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a brief example of two filters you can use:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter(YOURSTOREID, false)
        ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
```

This will get you all your active blocks on your Store.

You can add a order filter like this:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(YOURSTOREID, false)
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'DESC');
```